# Подписка на C# по RSS

Tags: c#, rss

Из веб-морды доступна ссылка
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#/?type=rss
Которая форвардит на веб-страницу
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c/#/?type=rss
Где кликая по RSS получаешь подписку на 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c/?type=rss
В котором C# и не пахнет, только С/С++

Comment: на мету напишите, там скорее помогут, если вообще...

Comment: @QuAzI, Пожалуйста, задавайте подобные вопросы на [Мете](http://meta.hashcode.ru). Обновили движок, коммит с исправлением дефекта в него вошел.

Answer (score 5):

Символ `#` в названии **C#** в урле является специальным символом (разделитель между хэшем и остальным урлом). Судя по всему, именно это ломает первую ссылку (ибо вторая и третья ваши ссылки уже неверны для C#)

Поздравляю, вы нашли баг! Этот символ должен быть url-закодирован - `%23`. А вот и годная ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23/?type=rss

---

**UPD** На все три тэга можно подписаться по такой ссылке: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#&c++&c/?type=rss](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%26c%2B%2B%26c%23/?type=rss)

Comment: Круто. А подписаться на все три C/C++/C# одним линком, как он это в браузере показывает, реально?

Comment: Реально, смотрите обновленный ответ